# i want to create a bot for game named (gun and bottles) using python

Tags: python

i want to make a bot on game named (gun and bottles) in python

this is the link of the game
https://gamesnacks.com/embed/games/aktestgunsandbottles

**i am thinking of an invisible radius (line moving in circular path with gun ) which can recognize pixel colors  , IF green pixel is encountered , (click) action will be triggered  , but how can i make a line which moves with the gun in circular direction and recognize the pixel color ?**

please help

i asked similar question on discord and got this

```
import clickclickclickclock

# border_edge = [(x, y), (x, y), (x, y), (x,y)]
center_pixel_loc = (x, y)
gun_tip_pixel_loc = (x, y)
bottle_pixel_loc = (x, y)

x1, y1 = center_pixel_loc[0], center_pixel_loc[1]
x2, y2 = gun_tip_pixel_loc[0], gun_tip_pixel_loc[1]
m = (y2 - y1) // (x2 - x1)
b = 0


if (bottle_pixel_loc[1] ==  m * bottle_pixel_loc[0] + b):
    shoot()

def shoot(): 
    click()
    sleep()
```

Comment: It might not always work, you need to also consider distance to the bottle (which varies with bottles trajectory) and bullet speed

Comment: That's too broad of a question as you're basically asking for the solution to your whole project maybe provide some code and narrow it down to a specific error that or problem that you encounter. You'd probably need to look into some math, idk vectors and polar coordinates might be useful maybe complex numbers could help as well, don't know how familiar you are with that. And in terms of the other stuff, you could use an automation library like idk pyautogui or autopy. There are libraries to take screenshots and let you manipulate images mss, PIL, cv2 so yeah there's a lot you could do.

Comment: @haxor789 i ask similar question on one of the discord server and got this```import time
import clickclickclickclock

# border_edge = [(x, y), (x, y), (x, y), (x,y)]
center_pixel_loc = (x, y)
gun_tip_pixel_loc = (x, y)
bottle_pixel_loc = (x, y)

x1, y1 = center_pixel_loc[0], center_pixel_loc[1]
x2, y2 = gun_tip_pixel_loc[0], gun_tip_pixel_loc[1]
m = (y2 - y1) // (x2 - x1)
b = 0


if (bottle_pixel_loc[1] ==  m * bottle_pixel_loc[0] + b):
    shoot()

def shoot(): 
    click()
    sleep()```

Comment: First of all I'm not sure if clickclickclickclock is a real library but as said there are libraries to simulate clicks that function similarly. What this essentially does is it computes the vector (the direction) from the center point to the tip of the gun. Now you'd need a condition for when the point on the bottle is on that imaginary line from the center to the tip of the gun. But I'm not sure what the condition in your example does and I doubt that it works. Also you'd still need ways to process the image to get the point on the bottle and the tip of the gun.